# How do I compute a new basis (transformation matrix) from a 3D plane and known origin?

Tags: 3d, geometry, plane, coordinate-transformation

Given a 3D plane and an arbitrary point on it that I want to consider the origin `(0,0,0)` of a new basis, it is possible to: (A) define a basis from this information?  And (B) create a transformation matrix that allows me to convert between world space and the new basis?

I can assume the transformation is affine.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but since you only have a plane the orientation of the new basis will be arbitrary.

Lets say you have a point **k** that lies on the plane **P** and you want point **k** as your origin. You have **P = (N, d)** where **N** is the normalised plane normal and **d** is the distance to the plane from the origin.

To determine an orthonormal basis with arbitrary orientation on this plane
Define 3 vectors right **R**, up **U** and normal **N**

We already have **N** which is nothing but the normal of the plane

```
U = (0,1,0)
// If U is pointing in almost the same direction as N, change it
if (U.N > 0.7071) U = (0, 0, 1);
R = normalise (U x N)
U = normalise (N x R) // U was not orthonormal
```

Now define a 3x3 transformation matrix **M** where the 3 rows of the matrix are R, U and N respectively.

```
      R
M = ( U )
      N
```

Now let us say you wanted to transform a point **p** to a point **p'** on your plane.

```
p' = M ( p - k )
```

If you want to do all this with one matrix you can combine M and the translation vector -k into a 4x4 homogeneous matrix.
Notes:

1. The .'s above are vector dot products
2. The x's above are vector  cross products

HTH